# Where do you change where "Your Projects" links point to in WAMP?

Tags: php, localhost, wamp

In WAMP we have a "Your Projects" section. When you add a folder to your "www" folder, the new folder is automatically detected and you can click on it to open it as if it was a running website. The server my website is hosted on gives us access higher than the "www" level, so if you do a `$_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT']` it points to a directory a couple levels above where our actual index.php lives.

I want to keep the configure.php as close to the actual server set up as possible, so if `$_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT']` points to the directory 2 levels above where the actual index.php is, that is how I would like to have it in WAMP as well so there is less tweaking when it goes back on the server.

Out of the box, WAMP points to the parent directory of the website and you need to follow a few links to open the actual website (in my case you click "honu" then "httpdocs", and then the page loads.)

I only need it for that one particular website, so I am not looking for a "hosts" change. (I changed "hosts" to point to 127.0.0.1 for a variety of names, but this only helps to get to the "localhost" location when you type the URL in a browser. I have `DocumentRoot "C:\wamp\www\honu\httpdocs"` set in httpd-vhosts.conf and this doesn't change the link in the "Your Projects" section.

Is there a place to configure the "Your Projects" to point one particular project to `localhost/subfolder/subsubfolder/`?

Comment: The problem I get with using the `httpd-vhosts.php` method is that "localhost" is linked directly to my folder rather than opening the WAMP www/index.php to allow different links

Comment: I think this post should help you http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23665064/project-links-do-not-work-on-wamp-server/23990618#23990618 Pay particular attention to the section marked **Now if you take this to its logical extension** and create the folder structure you need to imitate you live environment and put it outside the default WAMPServer folder structure. Also note the section on turning the **My Virtual Hosts** menu on

Comment: Thank you, I am doing this and when you point the browser to "example.dev" it goes to the files in "d:/websites/example.com/www" just fine, I even have my IDE pointed to the proper location and everything is happy in that part of my life. My hope was that I would be able to edit the link that is physically in the WAMP startup page, found when you run "localhost" (C:\wamp\www.index.php) out of WAMP.